# How to have scalable image with viewport in p5js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm making a website for my design studio and I would like to set image sizes with the p5js language.

Here, I made a function that allows each mouse click to display an image. The problem is that once the image is displayed, it appears at the indicated dimensions, adapt to the screen size but the ratio is not good. The image is either too wide or too extended.

so what do you need to do to display an image with the right original width/height ratio

All your feedback is appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

```js
let works = []

function preload() {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    works[i] = loadImage("img/work" + i + ".png")
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function draw() {
cursor(CROSS);
}

var counter = 0
function mouseClicked() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  counter++
        image(works[counter%6], mouseX, mouseY, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`image` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image) can take 3, 5, 7, or 9 parameters, and in each case it has different behavior:

- `image(img, x, y)` - Draw the entire image with it's original size at the specified location
- `image(img, x, y, width, height)` - Draw the entire image, scaled to the specified width and height **without** preserving aspect ratio, at the specified position.
- `image(img, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight)` - Draw a specific part of the image, scaled to the specified width and height without preserving aspect ratio, at the specified position.

The function of the `dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight` parameters is explained by this diagram:

[image: image size and position mapping]

In order to draw an image scaled relative to the window size constrained to the aspect ratio of the window, you will need to determine how best to crop your images.

```js
let works = []

function preload() {
    works[0] = loadImage("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/no_idea_why.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '1');
}

function draw() {
  cursor(CROSS);
}

var counter = 0

function mouseClicked() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  counter++
  let img = works[counter % works.length];
  let windowAspect = width / height;
  let imageAspect = img.width / img.height;
  let w, h;
  // This code naively crops the bottom or right edge of the image as necessary. Obviously there are other ways to limit the image size.
  if (windowAspect >= imageAspect) {
    // Our window is wider than our image, we need to constrain the height of the image
    w = img.width;
    h = w / windowAspect;
  } else {
    // Our window is narrower than or image, we need to constrain the width of the image
    h = img.height;
    w = h * windowAspect;
  }
  image(img, mouseX, mouseY, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 0, 0, w, h);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer Paul ! the problem with this solution is that the images are all cropped in the same way depending on the viewport. So my images in portrait orientation are cropped as landscape images for wide screens; and conversely my landscape images are cropped as portrait on narrow screens (phone for example). Is there any other way than crop the images?

Comment: It all comes down to how you compute the `dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight`. You can either crop, or you can add bars on the top/bottom or left/right sides. A lot of social media apps add a stretched, blurred version of the image in order to fit it into the desired aspect ratio without distracting black rectangles (i.e. letterboxing). Anything is possible, but you'll have to be specific about your desired effect if you want help with the code. I'd also suggest you at least take a pass at implementing the desired effect yourself, all the basic ingredients needed are there.

Comment: Note: if you want to blur things check out https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/filter . If you want to blur just one element after having already drawn elements to your main canvas you can use https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics to create an off-screen buffer, draw and blur things there, and the draw its contents to the main canvas using image.